# Rails - get unique column's "parent"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

It's a bit tricky to phrase the question but say I have an array of Objects named `Listing` that contains the columns:

```
irb(main):003:0> Listing.column_names
=> ["id", "content", "created_at", "updated_at", "page_id"]
```

And the Object `Page` which belongs_to another Object `Author`, and I want to populate all the unique Authors of all the Listings.

So something like:

```
listings.pages.where(|p| p.Author is unique)
```

But I want to get the Authors not the Pages. Is there a quick way to map this? what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making a few assumptions because it's not clear from your description:

```
Listing 
  belongs_to :page

Page
  belongs_to :author
  has_many :listings

Author
  has_many :pages
  has_many :listings, through: :pages
```

If that is correct then you could do something like:

```
listing_ids = Listing.where("some condition is met").pluck(:id)
Author.includes(:listings).where(listings: { id: listing_ids) })
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried:

```
listings.pages.distinct(:author)
```

It returns a list of all distinct author for the current selection, i.e. pages that are in your listing.

Comment: I get undefined method `pages' for #<Listing::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProx

Comment: I just used your example (`listings.pages`), but if listings is a collection, then iterate over it and for each listing get the distinct authors of the pages.

Answer (score 0):

Flip your thinking around.  Start with Author.

This will generate all the authors of all the pages that are in the specific listings.  If listing is a collection, you'll need to do something like this.

```
Author.joins(:pages => :listings).where('listings condition')
```

The join will ensure you only get authors that have a page in that particular listing (or listings)